# News Database Design for a Desktop Application

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am making an application that will process a big chunk of information. This information was retrieved using some web crawlers and is about news, containing data such as *News Title, URL, Publication Date, Category* and *Content*. The crawled data is in XML format, and I will load that information into my application.

From there, 10 users will process every news and tag the category of the news manually by reading the title. I've used 9 main categories to be used, and for each news the users will decide from 0-5 how much this particular news belongs to each category.

Users will also search for news by title and decide if this news is discussing the same event as another news, or if this news is similar to another news (like a news about a football game at 3 PM and a news about a football game at 5 PM).

I have no problems with making the application itself, I just need some help with the part of how to design one/many tables that can link news that talk about similar events or about the same event, since there can be many many news that can talk about the same event.

So far I've done something like this:

Table **News**

```
ID
Title
URL
PublicationDate
NewsContent
```

Table **Category**

```
NewsID
User_ID
Economy
Politics
Present_Day
Sport
Technology
Showbiz
Culture
Region
World
```

Table **User**

```
ID
FirstName
LastName
```

Each category field in the Category table holds a *tinyint* data type (I'm using SQL Server) and I've restricted the values the user can input via a check constraint so that it allows values from 0 - 5. I don't know if this is the right approach so far for the database design, and I need to add the table/s that allow to add information about similar news or news that talk about the same event, such as a table **Similar_News** containing some fields like News_ID, SimilarNews1_ID, SimilarNews2_ID and so on, and must contain the information about which user 'said this', but this sounds like a flawed design to me.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Rather than deal with a wide Category table, you might want to look into an EAV model so that adding categories doesn't mean adding columns. https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway

Answer (score -1):

Based on how dynamic this sounds like I would suggest looking at a NoSQL data structure. I do not use them so much myself, but looking into something like MongoDB might be worth it. Good luck on your application!